# Pinch zoom only zooms into center

Tags: java, android, gesture, android-gesture

I‘m trying to make an image in my app pinch-zoomable. It should be able to zoom into different parts of the image. As the code is right now, wherever I‘m doing the zooming gesture it only zooms into the center, so I have no chance to move the image or zoom into other areas.
What is necessary decenter the zoom and move the zoomed image?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
private ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());

    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            return true;
        }

    });
}


private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector){
        mScaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f,
                Math.min(mScaleFactor, 1.7f));
        mImageView.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
        mImageView.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);

        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, the best will be added this library:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Of course, or add this library as local module and customize it for your purposes.

Comment: Perfect, that indeed works for me! Are you familiar with that library so you could help me with an issue?

Comment: @MikeKng How could I help you? The usage is very simple, write me through chat at least.

Comment: That might be a problem, I‘m only logged in on my phone. But the problem I have is that before I had an image that was not moveable and with an onTouch method I could get the color of the touched pixel. This works now as long as the image is not moved, but when I‘m zooming in for example it returns wrong colors, like everything is displaced. But I couldn’t find a pattern in that fault. I‘m using the bitmap.getPixel() method so I thought it wouldn’t effect it when the image is moved. Shall I add it to my code above?